# how to redirect old urls to new urls to a new server

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I moved my website to a new server and I have problems with the redirects. The thing is that the domain is the same but the urls are new. I wanted to redirect one by one the most polular pages of the old site. I give you an example:

http://www.gamosorganosi.gr/cgi-bin/sstyle3.cgi?kod_sel=519 (old one)

http://www.gamosorganosi.gr/gamos/nifika/10/Sposa-Moda (new one to new server)

I tried redirect 301 and rewriteRule but it did not work. All of them were placed in the new site .htacces file.

The message I keep getting is:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /cgi-bin/sstyle3.cgi was not found on this server.

and on the title I see a 404title of the old site.

One last piece of information:the old site is still online with a new domain www.gamos-organosi.gr

How can i redirect them? Should I place the redirects in the old site?

Answer (score 0):

The redirects initiate from the old URL so the trend must be followed in the configuration. Since you're dealing with the same domain, the rules are very simple.

Put .htaccess at your document root and add this line:

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/sstyle3\.cgi\?kod_sel\=519$ http://www.gamosorganosi.gr/gamos/nifika/10/Sposa-Moda [R=301,L]
```

or for a bit more speed, edit the virtual host section of www.gamosorganosi.gr in httpd.conf (apache configuration file) and insert this:

```
<directory "/path/to/document_root">
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/sstyle3\.cgi\?kod_sel\=519$ http://www.gamosorganosi.gr/gamos/nifika/10/Sposa-Moda [R=301,L]
</directory>
```

The second idea does require a restart of the server but it does work if `/path/to/document_root` is replaced with the real path to your document root.

P.S. Just make sure you escape special characters used by the regex engine such as question mark and periods.

Comment: i am really sorry for asking but I am quite new to all this! When you say "the trend must be followed in the configuration" what do you mean exactly? Should I place the .htaccess with the redirects to the old site?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best way possible:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [R=301,L]
```

Meaning in the same domain use the subdirectory then forward to the actual 
url you are redirecting.

Having `[R=301,L]` is critical-- because it's telling the search engine also to redirect to the code `301` and `L` meaning the last rule for this specified redirect.